# No D-Link wifi after power interruption

Tags: 18.04, wireless

I have lost wifi on my Dlink dongle when I try chili555's fantastic reload that has worked before, i.e.:

```
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make clean
make ( **It messes up here** )
```

```
$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/build M=/home/joanne/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1049: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Some results of queries below:

```
$ lshw
*-usb:2 UNCLAIMED
                      description: Generic USB device
                      product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
                      vendor: Realtek
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: usb@2:1.3
                      version: 2.00
                      serial: 00e04c000001
                      capabilities: usb-2.10
                      configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q65 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Desktop SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
```

```
$ inxi
CPU~Quad core Intel Core i5-2400 (-MCP-) speed/max~1600/3400 MHz Kernel~4.4.0-116-generic x86_64 Up~2:07 Mem~1911.9/7862.7MB HDD~250.1GB(9.6% used) Procs~259 Client~Shell inxi~2.3.56
```

```
$ nmcli device
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION   
eno1    ethernet  connected  Auto Ethernet
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for joanne:
  *-network                
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: 78:2b:cb:a9:18:b3
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.0.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 memory:e1a00000-e1a1ffff memory:e1a80000-e1a80fff ioport:3080(size=32)
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q65 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Desktop SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0e8d:2008 MediaTek Inc.
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2001:3314 D-Link Corp.
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:0760 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Acer KU-0760 Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ nmcli g
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN   
connected  full          enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

```
$ nmcli g
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN   
connected  full          enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

```
joanne@joanne-OptiPlex-790:~$ nmcli n
enabled
```

```
joanne@joanne-OptiPlex-790:~$ nmcli r
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN   
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

```
joanne@joanne-OptiPlex-790:~$ nmcli c
NAME                      UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
Auto Ethernet             03d1561f-d6d4-4752-bd31-9e5af210bf3e  ethernet  eno1  
MIFI2-MXAM                9fd213c2-58da-418d-aa27-ad97fca962b7  wifi      --    
PrivatVPN-US-LA-TUN-1194  b885f4df-bd81-4321-ac06-743c094508e9  vpn       --    
RCMP 1                    6ada3fdc-1731-43ce-9248-475020d208fa  wifi      --    
RCMP 2                    82e3482a-a767-4afb-a7a1-b19e58177520  wifi      --
```

```
joanne@joanne-OptiPlex-790:~$ nmcli d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION   
eno1    ethernet  connected  Auto Ethernet
```

I am at a total loss on how to proceed.

Comment: does the router not reboot correctly? Is there a manual reset button? Try to disconnect all the connections from the router and try to access the router's IP.

Comment: Thanks karel for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are having trouble compiling the driver? Please try the following procedure:

Download archive into temp directory.

```
# mkdir -p /tmp/t4u
# cd /tmp/t4u
# wget https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/archive/master.zip
```

Unzip

```
# unzip master.zip
# cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master
```

Install kernel headers

```
# sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Compile and install from source

```
# make
# sudo make install
```

Load module

```
# sudo modprobe -a rtl8812au
```

This procedure is outlined on GitHub >>> https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Much appreciated. Now it is complaining about not finding headers. 
/tmp/t4u/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master$ sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic' has no installation candidate 

Suggestions?

Comment: @Rick Sidall I've had this before, will get back to you.

Comment: Thank you Raffles

Comment: @RickSiddall What version of Ubuntu are you running? It's late here so I will get back tomorrow.

Comment: @RickSiddal Your answer might lie here >> https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2394643

since the driver is rtl18812au and not rt18812au.

Comment: I can kick my butt, just enter the following command in a terminal and it should install the driver `sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms`

Comment: Similar error
make[1]: * /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1457: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: * [modules] Error 2e

Comment: It might then be your kernel, mine is `4.15.0-112-generic x86_64`, but I don't know offhand how to fix it. The driver installed without a hitch on two of my machines. You can also use Synaptic Package Manager to install and fix the driver

Comment: So I tried to update the kernel and this is the error on that.

DKMS make.log for rtl8812au-4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg for kernel 5.4.0-42-generic (x86_64)
Fri Jul 24 19:01:54 EDT 2020
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1457: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2

Comment: Good morning Rick. Please see this article on how to upgrade the kernel. Try to upgrade to the same kernel I have on 3 machines 4.15.0-112-generic as the wireless works fine on all my machines. Maybe @chili555 can assist as well.
https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-ubuntu-1804/

Comment: Hello Raffles. Well I tried both ways listed. No joy,  <br/>https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-ubuntu-1804/   
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa  
sudo apt-get install ukuu  
E: Unable to locate package ukuu  

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577034/installing-ukuu-on-ubuntu-18-04  

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppasudo apt-get install libgee-0.8-dev libjson-glib-dev libvte-2.91-dev valac  
git clone https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu.git  
`apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...

Comment: It looks like the ukuu package is no longer freeware >>> https://teejeetech.in/ukuu/ 
There must be another way to fix your kernel. Can you boot into a live session and see if the wifi works?

Comment: No luck with live session  
Does that mean hardware?  I got 2 system error messages on reboot.  Would you like me to post them?

Comment: Go ahead. You should make a live USB with Startup Disk Creator in the main menu and use the same version (18.04) fresh download. To boot into the live session, make sure the boot order in BIOS/UEFI is correct and that Secure Boot is disabled. Can you also make a USB ethernet connection (Settings>>>Connections>>>Mobile Hotspot and Tethering>>>USB tethering) with your cellphone to see if that works? Since your D-Link is recognized in the `lsusb` output.

Comment: No USB tether connection is possible and the System error messages have disappeared.

Comment: Just noticed that system time cannot be set by internet only manually very weird. This is happening while the ethernet cable is connected.